# Debugging Memory Leak with Chrome Heapdumps in Node App

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I'm trying to debug a Memory Leak in my Node/Express Application.
For debugging I automatically created heapsnapshots when Memory-Size increased. Over the last 2 weeks days I ended up with a nice colleciton of heapdumps (15).

But when loading these heapdumps into chrome inspector I can't seem to get anything useful out of them (comparing them). It seems that everything is just growing proportional to time.

Can anyone give me a Tip on how to extract something useful out of this data? All the articles I've read about memory leak debugging had setup some conveniantly obvious leaking function that was naturally displayed on top of the list. My reality seems way more complicated.

[image]

Comment: try out [node-clinic-doctor](https://github.com/nearform/node-clinic-doctor) It makes much easier than do it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for that, at this point I'd like to stick to the data I've already collected though. This seems to be one of the standard ways to debug memory leaks, so I'm still hoping on some input on how to proceed.